# How to let the height of an element follows the height of next element automatically without table element?

Tags: html, css

for example, I want an image next to textfield, and I want the height of textfield follows the height of image, I tried:

```html
<table>
  <tr style="height:auto;">
    <td style="height:100%;">
      <input style="height:100%;"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which I use avatar as sample image here, and I want the height of textfield
 would change automatically when I change another image which has different height.

I think the html code above is not simple, and I don't want to use table element to do that, is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Put them both in the same `<div>`

Comment: You can't set the height of the input box to 100% unless its container has an explicit height. This will work: `<td style="height:30px;"><input style=" display:block;width:auto;height:100%;"/>`

Comment: What Victor said; it's all about the container.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, I thought you said you didn't want to use a table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, assuming I understand your question:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input>
  <img 
src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d? 
s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input
{
    height: 90px;
    float: left;
 }
 div
 {
   float:left;
 }
 img
 {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
 }
```

and here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8t146hsg/7/